# Excel VBA trying to use a cell to store a variable calculation

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know very well how to word this so I apologize if this doesn't make a whole lot of sense :)

I want to be able to place the information for a variable into a cell in excel and then reference that in VBA. This is part of a find and replace macro I've created, so i am going to be looping through many rows. I want to put the data in a cell so that I can expand on what I loop through via the excel sheet.

this is the sample code that is successful:

```
Dim VarArray(1 To 3) As String

For i = 1 to 3
VarArray(i) = "ABC"
Next

Set rng = Range("D:D")
Varlookups = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "<>")

For j = 1 To 3
For k = 2 To Varlookups

Findtext = "take " & VarArray(j) & " tablet" 
Replacetext = "insert " & VarArray(j) & " tablet" 
Columns("B").Replace What:=Findtext, Replacement:=Replacetext, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Next
Next
```

I would like to be able to manually place these pieces in cells within excel:

Cell D2 = "take " & VarArray(j) & " tablet"

Cell E2 = "insert " & VarArray(j) & " tablet"

And then change my VBA formula to reference those cells:

```
Findtext = Range("D2").value
Replacetext = Range("E2").value
```

I've tried using evaluate with no success. I am really drawing a blank on how to accomplish this. Any help provided would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: `book.sheet.range("D2").value = "take " & VarArray(j) & " tablet"` Set book and sheet accordingly.

Comment: I'm not trying to use VBA to set those cells to be "take " & VarArray(j) & " tablet" and "insert " & VarArray(j) & " tablet" .

Comment: What I'm trying to do is use what is in those cells in order to perform the find and replace. I want to manually type "take " & VarArray(j) & " tablet" into cell D2. I then want my VBA code to take that and evaluate it into the variable Findtext the same way as if I had placed that text to the right of the equals sign in VBA. Findtext for the first loop through should evaluate as "take ABC tablet" due to the variable VarArray(j). When I just used Findtext = Range("D2").value it instead evaluates as the whole string  "take " & VarArray(j) & " tablet". Thank you for your reply though :)

Comment: That's a rather convoluted way of doing it XD You clearly know how to use variables. Use them!

Comment: Yes, I agree with @findwindow. Why do you want to store the `VBA` code in a cell when you already have it right in your code? If you do this, you have to replace the text of `VarArray(j)` with the real value of the `VarArray(j)` in the code anyway. The only reason I can think of at all to do it like this is if you have A LOT of examples and you want to be able to change them easily in the spreadsheet if needed. (I have seen something similar to this before). If that is what you need, let me know and I will provide a solution for that.

Comment: Thats pretty much exactly what I'm going for. this is a growing find/replace macro where i want to be able to keep adding new items to find/replace. What I am doing with the VarArray in a separate part of the code is storing the numeric values from the cells im performing my find and replaces on and then later on re-adding them back into the doc. so "take 1 tablet", "take 2 tablet", etc both at this point in the code would be "take variable tablet". however, that variable will be different based on the amount of numeric values there are in the string i'm find/replacing on.

Comment: Consider editing the property of an invisible object instead of a cell. For example, the title of an invisible shape. This prevents unintential manipulation of the variable by an Excel user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the range value from which sheet like this..

```
Findtext = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value
Replacetext = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").value

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value = "take " & VarArray(j) & " tablet"

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value= "insert " & VarArray(j) & " tablet"
```

Hope this helps you :)